# how can install eclipse sdk on windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed eclipse sdk  on ubuntu and i used it well for a month.
I formatted my PC and when i tried to install eclipse ADT, the AVD BUTTON and Android sdk manger button didn't appear.
I update the ADT and formatting PC many times and without vain.
I tried to installed eclipse on windows 7 when i installed the ADT the android's button appear but didn't run and an error's message appears.
I want to downloaded eclipse from developer.android.com when i clicked "Download Eclipse ADT with the android SDK for windows" and then i clicked the check box and submit but the file download doesn't start and i get this link   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt?

Comment: Try https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Comment: to be frank i use android and its components, but i do not install nothing, jux run them.. its quicker..lol

Comment: @Gumbo: this link of adt only or eclipse+adt??

Comment: This is the whole package. You just extract it somewhere and run the eclipse.exe. You will still need to download the APIs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find eclipse + Android SDK bundle http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Pick "Eclipse ADT" and then go to the link inside "download the Eclipse ADT bundle now"

Or

Windows 32bits
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

Windows 64bits
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Linux 32bits
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

Linux 64bits
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip

Mac OS
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

---

## Update

Eclipse probably will be deprecated

Fast forward to [8 December 2014](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio10released), Android Studio 1.0 has been released:

> After two years of development, we're extremely happy to announce that
>   Android Studio 1.0 has finally been released! We would like to thank
>   all of our early access users for their feedback and bug reports which
>   helped shape the IDE.

Currently Android's official website writes:

> If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio
>   is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android
>   Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates. For help moving
>   projects, [see Migrating to Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).
>
> Considering the choppy politics of the Android platform, having
>   Android Studio being labeled "official" does seem like Eclipse's ADT
>   plugin will be getting subpar treatment, which is probably the very
>   definition of being de facto deprecated.

Comment: i tried it and i get this link <http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt>

Comment: @HmidiSlim what about now?

Comment: same thing i thought the problem on my PC.

Comment: @HmidiSlim Now you have direct links. It's imposible you can't download it now :)

Comment: thanks I'm downloading it,when the download finish i will extract it on eclipse's folder??

Comment: @HmidiSlim wherever you want, just unzip and go inside of directory and you will find eclipse and ADT directories. Inside eclipse directory you can find eclipse executable.